# Virtualization VT-x in intel core i7 4700mq not enabled

Tags: virtualization, intel

I have the following problem, when I go to the bios and I enable the Virtualization Technology, the "Intel Processor Identification Utility" says that I don't have Virtualization Technology. But when I disable it, it says that I do have that available. 
Any ideas on why Virtualization is not being enabled? I have windows 8.1 pro. pocessor is intel core i7 4700MQ. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i have the same problem...
did you find a solution?

Comment: nope I didn't. Let me know if you find it.